# Convex compact closure

Tags: field-theory, convex-analysis

Let X $\subset R^n $  be a convex compact. Does this mean that the equality $cl(coneX) = cone X$ holds?
Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Convex and compact are independent concepts. What is $cone$?

Comment: To have equality, you need to assume that $0\notin X.$ See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2366003/cone-generated-by-a-w-compact-set-is-w-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $X$ be the ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$, centred at $(0,1)$ of radius $1$. Then the cone generated by $X$ is the open halfplane union the origin, while the closed cone generated by $X$ is the closed halfplane.

Comment: Then the cone generated by $X$ is the open halfplane union the origin, while the closed cone generated by $X$ is the closed halfplane. Can you please explain this with an example?

Comment: Hi @Maneesh: This is the example, just draw a picture and it will become clear.

Comment: What is the def'n of the cone generated by $X$?

Comment: A cone is a set that is closed under multiplication by positive scalars. The cone generated by $X$ is the smallest cone containing $X$. This is like in linear algebra, with the span being the smallest subspace containing a given set. Since the set $X$ is assumed to be convex, the cone generated by $X$ can be shown to be convex as well.